# Kubernetes pod fails to deploy; docker image is missing/misplacing a file?

Tags: docker, npm, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to learn my way around Kubernetes with Google Cloud Platform. I have a small Vue-based application working locally with the following `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.

Building and bringing up this project locally works great. However, when using `kompose up` to create a deployment/svc/etc. for this thing, the container fails to build properly. Ultimately it ends up in a crashing loop.

Inspecting the logs shows that the issue is that `npm` cannot find `/opt/eyeball/package.json` or `/opt/eyeball/package-lock.json`. I'm confused since this isn't an issue when I build and push the image that my cluster is ultimately pulling down - those files are right where you'd expect them to be based on my `Dockerfile`. Any idea why this might be happening?

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM node:8-alpine
RUN apk --no-cache --update add gzip
RUN mkdir -p /opt/eyeball
ADD ./package.json /opt/eyeball
ADD ./package-lock.json /opt/eyeball
WORKDIR /opt/eyeball
RUN npm install
ADD . /opt/eyeball
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: overmind

services:
  eyeball:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/souldeux/eyeball:latest
    environment:
      - HOST=0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/eyeball
    entrypoint: "npm run dev"
```

Comment: What happens if you delete the `volumes:` block in the `docker-compose.yml`?  That has the effect of overwriting basically everything that gets installed in the `Dockerfile` with what's on your host system, which I'm guessing your Kubernetes Deployment doesn't do.  I'd also delete the custom `entrypoint:` line unless you know the Deployment spec has something similar.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks very much. You were right about `entrypoint` as well; it needed to be changed to a `command`. If you'd like to post this as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delete the `volumes:` block in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

The `volumes:` block in your `docker-compose.yml` directs Docker to take the contents of your local directory and mount them into the container, which hides everything that you add in the `Dockerfile`.  When you deploy this with Kompose, this gets translated to Kubernetes directives, but since the Kubernetes environment doesn't have your local development environment, this results in the deployed containers failing.